# Fading images in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I fade out all the images inside the class bMenu that are not #b2 with jQuery? Thanks.

```
<div class="bMenu" id="b1"><img src='b1.jpg'></div>
<div class="bMenu" id="b2"><img src='b2.jpg'></div>
<div class="bMenu" id="b3"><img src='b3.jpg'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img', '.bMenu:not(#b2)').fadeOut();
```

Comment: the DIV means it's the CONTEXT of IMG (second parameter to jQuery function), so this answer should work also as yours gnarf :)

Comment: I edited my post without noting it, sorry about that. So gnarf's comment was correct..

Comment: @juraj - yeah he had `$('img:not(#b2)', '.bMenu');` when I posted that comment :)

Comment: @grarf :-D that's why Edit changes should be sometimes appended without allowing rewrite

Answer (score 2):

Literal answer:

```
$(".bMenuL:not(#b2) img").fadeOut();
```

Assuming you want to make sure that the `#b2 img` is shown as well:

```
$("#b2 img").fadeIn();
```

Comment: I'd really like to know why this got a -1

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.bMenu:not(#b2) img').fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

Get it all done at once with chaining:

```
$("#b2 img").show().parent().siblings(".bMenu").find("img").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#('.bMenu > img').each(function(it){
    if(it.attr('id') != 'b2'){
        it.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Might be a way to do it with pure selectors but this should work.

Added Later:

Ok, I went and did a test... here is what I came up with:

```
$('div[id!=b2].bMenu > img').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

This selector will return two images, not the one with b2.

Comment: Again, `#b2` is the `div` not the `img`

Comment: Oops... then it.parent().attr('id') != 'b2' or something similar. I think the other answers should work too.